# Classification of discontinuities of a function which looks continuous

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity

I have to classify the discontinuities of a function which seems to me like a continuous.
It is given:

> $g(x)=((cos(x+2)-1)*sin(\frac{1}{x+2})$ , $x\in \mathbb R \setminus \{ -2\} $ and $f(-2)=0$

g(x) looks like it has an "Essential discontinuity" at x=-2, but I can't prove it. In the following, [you can see my try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNVeY.png) :

(I can show that around x=-2 the "points"/values are located on 0. But I don't know how to go on).

I would appreciate it if someone could help me find my mistake!

Comment: It's continuous everywhere. The reason is that $\sin$ is bounded and $\cos(x+2)-1 \to 0$ as $x\to -2$.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help @AndrewZhang ! So in the Funktion g(x) is no discontinuity, even it looks like a Essential discontinuity at x=-2. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't know what an essential discontinuity is, but yes, $g$ is continuous everywhere.